# Decision table reduction

Tags: decision-trees

Consider the following Decision table : 
[image]

The following is the reduction process of this table : 
[image]

[image]

The above table is the reduced table. But my question why we can't reduce further rule number 3 and 4  Since they differs only in A ?
And Also rule number 1&5&7 should has  don't care at the condition B ?